# react-mapbox-gl-geocoder not updating in child component after parent rerenders it

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl

I have a list of addresses I am rendering from a parent component using the listAddresses function.  It sets up a three-column row where the first row is a Mapbox Geocoder, the second is a react-bootstrap Form.Control text input, and the last is a p-tag, which for the sake of testing, is supposed to remove the entire row when clicked.

It works as intended for the form control and p-tag, but the Geocoder column only removes the final element in the list when any of the p-tags are pressed to trigger the removeLetter function.  Images of this are attached.

I am trying to remove the entire row corresponding to the p-tag that's clicked. In the first image I attached, it shows the child component Locations rendering the addresses passed in as props from the parent. In the second, it shows the result of what happens when the p-tag corresponding to letter 'a' is clicked; the proper p-tag and corresponding Form.Control input are removed correctly, but the wrong (the very last) Geocoder is removed.

```
// In Locations.js - the child component

listAddresses = () => {
    let addresses = []
    for(let i=0; i<this.props.addresses.length; ++i) {
        addresses.push(
            <div id='addressGrid' key={i}>
                <Geocoder
                    initialInputValue={this.props.addresses[i]}
                    //value={this.props.addresses[i]}.  <---- I tried this as well
                    mapboxApiAccessToken={mapboxApiAccessToken}
                    updateInputOnSelect={true}
                    viewport={this.props.viewport}
                    onSelected={(viewport, item)=>{
                        console.log(viewport, ' ', item)
                        this.props.addAddress({
                                address: item.place_name,
                                addressLongitude: item.geometry.coordinates[0],
                                addressLatitude: item.geometry.coordinates[1]
                            }
                        , this.props.index) }}
                        showLoader={true} />
                <Form.Control type='text' value={this.props.addresses[i] + 1} />
                <p onClick={()=>this.props.removeLetter(i)}>{this.props.addresses[i]}</p>
            </div>)
    }
    return addresses
}

removeLetter = index => {
    let addresses = [...this.state.addresses]
    addresses.splice(index, 1)
    this.setState({addresses})
}
```

The parent component initializes addresses as so before passing them as props to the child component:

```
// In Parent component 

this.state = {
   addresses: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}

<Locations 
    addresses={this.state.addresses} 
    addAddress={this.addAddress}
    removeAddress={this.removeAddress}
    removeLetter={this.removeLetter}
    viewport={this.state.viewport}
    setViewport={this.setViewport}
    moveViewport={this.moveViewport} />
```

[Image of initial addresses rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYzLD.png)

[Image of addresses after p-tag corresponding to letter 'a' is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7FSz.png)

Comment: Hi there and welcome on StackOverflow. It's pretty hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, or at least I don't get it. After your explanation try to briefly explain what the expected behaviour is and what it is doing now.

Comment: Trisma, thanks for the prompt reply!  I edited my question to make it more thorough.  I am trying to remove the entire row corresponding to the p-tag that's clicked.  In the first image I attached, it shows the child component Locations rendering the addresses passed in as props from the parent.  In the second, it shows the result of what happens when the p-tag corresponding to letter 'a' is clicked; the proper p-tag and corresponding Form.Control input are removed correctly, but the wrong (the very last) Geocoder is removed.

Comment: Maybe it has anything to do with `value={this.props.addresses[i] + 1}` ? Or maybe that you use `this.setState({addresses})}` in the Child component while you are passing addresses as a prop. I'm trying to understand how it all works

Comment: The form control associated with `value={this.props.addresses[I] + 1} is working correctly.  When the letter on the very right (a, b, or c) is clicked, it is removed, and so is the corresponding Form Control immediately to its left.  However, the Geocoder on the very left is not.

When 'a' is clicked, it removes the 'a' text at the very right, the Form.Control in the middle, but not the corresponding 'a' Geocoder.  Rather, it removes the last Geocoder in the column (in this case, corresponding to one rendered in row 'c').